# Moodle installation 2.7? are there any known login vulnerabilities?

Tags: moodle

Guys I am planning to use moodle 2.7 as the lms in my organization..could you please let me know if there are any know vulnerabilities which could grant a user a higher order privilege?? if yes then how do I make sure I fix it...I have to use moodle 2.7 only..cannot upgrade that

Answer (score 0):

Moodle 2.7 is out of support in about 6 weeks.  It's patched (security wise) **as of this point in time**, but if someone discovers something 3 months from now, it won't be fixed and you'll have to upgrade anyway.  It's a really, *really* bad idea to use it for a new site when you might as well use 3.1 (LTS) or 3.2